# EEEEK! My puzzle disappeared!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

$%Insert30characters,please..$

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8YRz.png) is related/relevant.

Comment: I'll never pull this solve off. I just wanted to say I really love this idea.

Comment: @qwertyu63 - thanks! But the solution is, in my opinion, actually pretty easy :)

Comment: I'm guessing the link in the comments is some sort of anagram? Man does my brain hurt.

Comment: @TimothyG. - nope. Mwahahahah.

Comment: There are exactly 30 characters(letters+numbers) in the imgur. Do we simply need to enter those in there? :p

Comment: @Techidiot o_O That was coincidental....

Comment: All I can notice is it says xkcd. That can't be a coincidence

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Confirmed as an accident in TSL :D

Comment: @Techidiot that's.... unbelievable. I mean... what? How? Whu... :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil lol. I seriously think, there should have been a *question*  at least to make a context :)

Comment: @Techidiot - nah. That would spoil it :P

Comment: With AWS S3/Imgur being down, I'm not sure if the missing image is part of the puzzle or not.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - no broken images are intended to be in the puzzle.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Clicking the (all white) image in the post gives:

> [image]
>  This is a gif that temporarily highlights five letters. Putting those into a stack.imgur URL gives:

The second image:

> [image]
>  Five of those diamonds have numbers in them. (In the case of "9", it's a tally mark for some reason.) This leads to:

The third image:

> [image]
>  The first letters of each word spell **LITERATURE STACK EXCHANGE: THIS IS AN AD FOR IT**. :/

Comment: Wow.  I'm blown away by this.  I opened and closed the first image so many times and failed to notice that the letters do that since its too fast. Even if i made it to the last image, I wouldn't be able to make sense of it. Amazing.

Comment: "This is a gif that temporarily highlights five letters." I'm confused. I get a png that doesn't temporarily do anything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - the .png ending doesn't matter - it's actually a gif. The red letters only last for 20 milliseconds, so...

Comment: I don't understand the second clue.

Comment: @MouseEvent: Look at the bottom of the "2" diamond. There's a faint number 1, meaning 2 is the first character. (Similarly, "g" is the fourth, with its number also at the bottom.)

Answer (score 21):

> Is this just a promotion for [literature.stackexchange.com](http://literature.stackexchange.com)? Clicking on the first link, the letters to the imgur file blink red. Next, you can order the letters that have numbers present in the corner of their diamond (I can't see the third letter, but you only have to check five to find it) to find the next image. Finally, taking the first letter of each word in the book says "Literature stack exchange - this is an ad for it."